# Android ICS Activity Transition from Fade In/Out Back to Slide

Tags: android, transition

I have an app where I used default slide in/out effects on standards activities and fade in/out on a few specific activities.

I've noticed that the new Android 4.X (ICS) has a different default, which is exactly fade in/out.

**How can i define on my standard activities my slide in/out effect?**

I've been trying to define it with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);                  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_out_right, 0);
}
```

To reproduce the fade in / out effect i'm using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.fade_in);                  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0);
}
```

but haven't managed to successfully reproduce it.

Also, I'm using this code on onCreate and onPause, is this correct? Or is there a better place to put it?

Thanks

PS: I've seen this [New Android 4.0 Screen Transitions Between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654379/new-android-4-0-screen-transitions-between-activities) but now answer has been provided.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

overridePendingTransition() has to be called immediately after starting the new activity, so you would call it after startActivity(intent), for example. 
To make a default you can create a class that extends Activity and override startActivity, onBackPressed(), etc. to override the transition. For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_transition,R.anim.slide_out_transition);
}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    super.startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_transition,R.anim.slide_out_transition);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_transition,R.anim.slide_out_transition);
}



}
```

Then, just extend MyActivity instead of Activity in your activities and the transitions should all be sliding by default.

Comment: The default transitions are slide_in_left and slide_out_right. You used other names.. so can you define the XML for them?

Comment: I usually define my own, but I see no reason why you can't use the defaults.

Comment: +1 how can I call the default one? DO I need to create a new xml for the default?

Comment: You can use android.R.anim.slide_in_left, for example. Have a look at NeTeInStEiN's code above for more examples.